# Android Widgets и SDK для Windows приложений

Tags: java, android, windows, gui

Философский вопрос настиг у меня. 
***Возможно ли использовать Android виджеты для создания Windows приложений?***

Если так задуматься, JetBrains выпустили [Compose библиотеку](https://github.com/jetbrains/compose-jb) для Windows. Но это не то. Мне нравится Android SDK с нативной Java, где я с помощью XML верски могу создавать интерфейсы. Да, есть C# со своим WPF и UWP, но C# для меня не особо понятный язык, хоть эти два языка часто сравнивают. Так возможно ли впихнуть Android SDK с нативной Java для Windows? Как по мне, это было бы очень интересно и (ИМХО) Java Desktop разработка могла бы продолжить свое существование.

Material Library не подходит для Windows? Люди успешно создают Fluent Design для Flutter и, я уверен, создадут (или уже есть) такой же дизайн для Android виджетов.

Хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение по этому поводу.

Comment: Напрямую такого пока нет, но есть JavaFX, где лейауты можно формировать на XML разметке - очень похоже на Android виджеты/вьюшки. Работает кроссплатформенно, даже есть попытки порта JavaFX на Android

Comment: Считаю, что JavaFX устарел, я пытался его использовать, но это скорее больше проблем приносит, чем приятного